# Concatenating one attribute of JSON from multiple into one file using jq

Tags: json, bash, merge, jq

I have multiple JSON files that are of similar form, here are two examples:

message_1.json

```
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "Person One"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person Two"
    }
  ],

  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "Person One",
      "timestamp_ms": 0002,
      "content": "Text2.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person Two",
      "timestamp_ms": 0001,
      "content": "Text1.",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Person One",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "Regular",
  "thread_path": "inbox/SomeString"
}
```

message_2.json

```
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "Person One"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person Two"
    }
  ],

  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "Person Two",
      "timestamp_ms": 0004,
      "content": "Text4.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person One",
      "timestamp_ms": 0003,
      "content": "Text3.",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Person One",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "Regular",
  "thread_path": "inbox/SomeString"
}
```

Is there a way I can use `jq` to merge the JSON files so that the `messages` attribute is concatenated (order doesn't matter) and the others are left alone?

The result from merging message_1.json and message_2.json would look like this:

messages.json

```
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "Person One"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person Two"
    }
  ],

  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "Person One",
      "timestamp_ms": 0002,
      "content": "Text2.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person Two",
      "timestamp_ms": 0001,
      "content": "Text1.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person Two",
      "timestamp_ms": 0004,
      "content": "Text4.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person One",
      "timestamp_ms": 0003,
      "content": "Text3.",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Person One",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "Regular",
  "thread_path": "inbox/SomeString"
}
```

I have 11 JSON files, message_1.json, ..., message_11.json. I would like to merge them all into one `messages.json` file of this form containing **all of the messages** across the JSON files. How can I do this using `jq` via bash?

Comment: What do you want as the final output?

Comment: @peak Thanks, I have added a sentence for clarification -- is it clear now?

Comment: @chepner I want one large JSON file of the same format containing all of the messages that were in the other JSON files.

Comment: At the very least, show two *small* input files and the expected result of the merger.

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible example with two small JSON files and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, which has the advantage of not requiring the -s option, which would consume more memory than necessary:

```
jq 'reduce inputs as $in (.;
  .messages += $in.messages)
' $(for i in $(seq 1 11); do echo message_$i.json ; done)
```

Notice that in this case, jq should be invoked *without* the -n option.

Comment: Since the Q is tagged bash you can use brace expansion instead of that for loop; like `jq ... message_{1..11}.json`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql) together with jq:

```
$ jq -c . message_*.json | spyql -Oindent=2 "SELECT first_agg(json->participants) AS participants, list_agg(json->messages) AS messages FROM json EXPLODE json->messages TO json"
```

jq is transforming the jsons into json lines format (1 json per line) and then spyql outputs a single json with the first occurrence of participants and all occurrences of messages concatenated into a single array.

Disclaimer: I am the author of spyql.

Answer (score -2):

One way, using slurp mode, which puts all the JSON files contents into a single array and then processes it by appending all the other object's messages to the first one in that array:

```
$  jq -s 'reduce .[1:][] as $m (.[0]; .messages += $m.messages)' message_*.json
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "Person One"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person Two"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "Person One",
      "timestamp_ms": 2,
      "content": "Text2.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person Two",
      "timestamp_ms": 1,
      "content": "Text1.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person Two",
      "timestamp_ms": 4,
      "content": "Text4.",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Person One",
      "timestamp_ms": 3,
      "content": "Text3.",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Person One",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "Regular",
  "thread_path": "inbox/SomeString"
}
```

Comment: `message*.json` probably won’t sort the files in numerical order.

Comment: @peak So? OP said *order doesn't matter* in his question.

Comment: I was just making an observation.

Comment: Btw I downvoted because slurping the input that you'll expand for using with reduce is an antipattern, it is a bad practice